# JAXB Annotated Child Class Using Super Classes XMLRootElement Name Value

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm using JAXB 2.1 and I'm confused by the XML output I'm seeing.  Below I have two child classes that extend the same parent.  When marshalled and viewed as XML in a browser using REST, Child class 1 (GeoLocationDecodedPayload) always has a root element of *geoLocationDecodedPayload* as expected.  For some reason child class 2 (AltitudeDecodedPayload) **doesn't** have *altitudeDecodedPayload* as its root element which is unexpected as its specified in its @XMLRootElement annotation.  The XML output shows the super class (GeoPayload) @XMLRootElement of *geoPayload*.  Any ideas why these two class act differently?

**child class 1:**

```
package com.api.model.vo.decoder;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import com.api.util.decoder.DecoderConstants;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "geoLocationDecodedPayload")
public class GeoLocationDecodedPayload extends GeoPayload implements Serializable {

   public GeoLocationDecodedPayload() {}

}
```

**child class 2:**

```
package com.api.model.vo.decoder;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import com.api.util.decoder.DecoderConstants;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "altitudeDecodedPayload")
public class AltitudeDecodedPayload extends GeoPayload implements Serializable {

    public AltitudeDecodedPayload() {}

}
```

**parent class:**

```
package com.api.model.vo.decoder;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "geoPayload")
public class GeoPayload {

    public GeoPayload() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgot to include AltitudeDecodedPayload.class in the below.  This fixed my issue.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name="payloadResponse")
public class PayloadResponse extends AbstractResponse{
    @XmlElementWrapper(name="decodedPayloads")
    @XmlElementRefs({
        @XmlElementRef(type=GeoPayload.class),
        @XmlElementRef(type=GeoLocationDecodedPayload .class),
        @XmlElementRef(type=AltitudeDecodedPayload .class)
```